# Xcode 5 crashes on save after editing the main menu

Tags: xcode, cocoa

How to find out why Xcode crashes every time I try to save after editing the main menu? It only happens in one project but the backtrace and error messages don't seem to show any project classes or resources.

This is from the crash report:

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 5A1413
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-4510/Framework/Document/Archiving/IBDocumentArchiver.m:164
Details:  IBCIImage is not registered in the schema
Object:   <IBDocumentArchiver: 0x7f99724859f0>
Method:   -archiveObject:forOptionalKey:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9968c14b90>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010854f188 -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x00000001072e3655 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001072e3984 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010a8fa9d6 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x000000010a8fac85 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000010a8fbca1 __64-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveDictionary:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x000000010a8fb8d2 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveDictionary:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x000000010a90f7f1 -[CIFilter(IBDocumentArchiving) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x000000010a8faa77 __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000010a8fa937 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x000000010a8fac85 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000010a8fd454 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000010a691610 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x00000001111c5e2f -[NSControl(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 16  0x00000001111bbe40 -[NSTableView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 17  0x000000010a8faa77 __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x000000010a8fa937 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x000000010a8fb71f __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 22  0x000000010a8fb55e -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x000000010a8fd67b -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x000000010a6914ee -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x00000001111ba55e -[NSClipView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 26  0x000000010a8faa77 __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 27  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 28  0x000000010a8fa937 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 29  0x000000010a8fac85 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 30  0x000000010a8fd454 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x000000010a691552 -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32  0x00000001111be370 -[NSScrollView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 33  0x000000010a8faa77 __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x000000010a8fa937 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x000000010a8fb71f __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38  0x000000010a8fb55e -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39  0x000000010a8fd67b -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:defaultValue:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x000000010a6914ee -[NSView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x00000001111c4c72 -[NSCustomView(IBDocumentArchivingGenerator) archiveWithDocumentArchiver:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 42  0x000000010a8faa77 __51-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 43  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 44  0x000000010a8fa937 -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveObject:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x000000010a8fb71f __59-[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 47  0x000000010a8fb55e -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveArray:withName:forOptionalKey:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 48  0x000000010a6a6154 -[IBDocument archiveTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 49  0x000000010a6a61cf -[IBDocument archiveAndVerifyArchivingOfTopLevelObjects:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 50  0x000000010a6a6762 -[IBDocument archiveDocument:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51  0x000000010a8f9e5f -[IBDocumentArchiver recurseWithElementNamed:forObject:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 52  0x000000010a8fa12e -[IBDocumentArchiver archiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53  0x000000010a8fa42e -[IBDocumentArchiver dataFromArchiveDocument:withType:compatibilityVersion:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54  0x000000010a6a89e2 -[IBDocument dataOfType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 55  0x00007fff85e3992e -[NSDocument fileWrapperOfType:error:] (in AppKit)
 56  0x000000010a6b34c6 -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 57  0x00000001111e43fa -[IBCocoaDocument fileWrapperOfType:options:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration)
 58  0x000000010a6b3588 -[IBDocument fileWrapperOfType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 59  0x00007fff859f8bdf -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in AppKit)
 60  0x000000010a697c99 -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 61  0x00007fff859f8a02 -[NSDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in AppKit)
 62  0x000000010a69d6fb -[IBDocument writeToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:originalContentsURL:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 63  0x00007fff859f82ce -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:forceTemporaryDirectory:error:] (in AppKit)
 64  0x00007fff859f8014 -[NSDocument _writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
 65  0x00007fff859f7b99 -[NSDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in AppKit)
 66  0x000000010840b95a -[IDEEditorDocument writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:] (in IDEKit)
 67  0x00007fff859f7337 __block_global_90 (in AppKit)
 68  0x00007fff85a04aef __block_global_97 (in AppKit)
 69  0x00007fff85a049ee __block_global_96 (in AppKit)
 70  0x00007fff85e40da0 __block_global_89 (in AppKit)
 71  0x00007fff8300affd __110-[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:writingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:]_block_invoke_0303 (in Foundation)
 72  0x00007fff82e2fbee -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _invokeAccessor:orDont:thenRelinquishAccessClaimForID:] (in Foundation)
 73  0x00007fff82e06c56 -[NSFileCoordinator(NSPrivate) _coordinateReadingItemAtURL:options:writingItemAtURL:options:error:byAccessor:] (in Foundation)
 74  0x00007fff859f6ec9 -[NSDocument _fileCoordinator:coordinateReadingContentsAndWritingItemAtURL:byAccessor:] (in AppKit)
 75  0x00007fff859f6cc7 __66-[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 (in AppKit)
 76  0x00007fff859f5f2f -[NSDocument performAsynchronousFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in AppKit)
 77  0x00007fff859f6920 -[NSDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:] (in AppKit)
 78  0x000000010857eb44 __73-[IDEEditorDocument saveToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 79  0x000000010857d0dd __50-[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:]_block_invoke69 (in IDEKit)
 80  0x00007fff859f1869 -[NSDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in AppKit)
 81  0x00000001083efb0f -[IDEEditorDocument continueFileAccessUsingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 82  0x00007fff859f6174 __block_global_18 (in AppKit)
 83  0x000000010857d47e __68-[IDEEditorDocument continueAsynchronousWorkOnMainThreadUsingBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
 84  0x00007fff85e6b662 __block_global_44 (in AppKit)
 85  0x00007fff885f7cd2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 86  0x00007fff885b847f __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 87  0x00007fff885dc7e4 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 88  0x00007fff885dc0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 89  0x00007fff85d4706b -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] (in AppKit)
 90  0x00007fff85d45ce0 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] (in AppKit)
 91  0x00007fff85d451a3 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] (in AppKit)
 92  0x00007fff85c02143 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 93  0x000000010835175b -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 94  0x00007fff85b1821a -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 95  0x00007fff85abcbd6 NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 96  0x00007fff8726a7e1 start (in libdyld.dylib)
 97  0x0000000000000002
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from Apple forums:

> There is a known issue with documents using CIFilter effects on NSView instances. You can remove the reference to any CIImage's in the Effects Inspector to workaround the bug.

Comment: Superb.  Fixed my crash.  Found with `find . -type f -exec grep -i CIImage {} \; -print`